# handling a job with spawn (start, termination) with socket-io Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, child-process

I have two questions here:

1. is there any way to manage child_proccess (spawn) which running with nodejs?
2. suppose I have a script that starts do some functionality, I need to start the execution with socket.io event. I need to stop this execution with another socket io event.

the first idea that came through my mind was :

start execution command with **spawn** and store the PID of the job in Redis. in the stop event, get PID from Redis and kill that process with another spawn with below command:

```
kill = spawn(`kill ${PID}`)
```

but os kernel does not allow nodejs to kill that process unless nodejs runs with **sudo** command.I am the owner of that **child_procces**. why I can't stop that?

the second Idea is to use global variable :

```
io = ()=>{
let job = null;
socket.on("start", ()=>{
    job = spawn("path/to/my/script")
})
socket.on("stop", ()=>{
   job.kill() // or procces.kill(job.pid)
})


}
```

so  I am so confused about managing child processes with nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to declare your job variable with **var** keyword.

when you execute the spawn command, the **spawn** it self generates two child process . you can use this trick for terminating the main child proccess that responsible for your job .

```
let PID = job.pid

kill = spawn(`kill ${PID+1}`)
```

this is not the desire answer but that will do your job if your child process is limited to short number